# How can I make human readable a google chart line with large variations?

Tags: angular, google-visualization

The image graph represents the number of users per day over two years (730 days). At the moment it is far from being human readable. How can I make it more human readable?

The options on the chart at this point are:

```
options = {
  colors: elevenColors,
  vAxis: { minValue: 0, format: '0', maxTextLines: 1 },
  hAxis: { textPosition: 'none' },
  legend: { position: 'none' },
  dataOpacity: 0.7,
  chartArea: {'width': '90%', 'height': '80%'},
  }
```

I've already tried increasing the maxValue, and changing the graph to scatter type (I'm open to changing the graph type as long as it's more readable), but nothing seems to work since the sample seems to be too big.

[image: Graph]

Answer (score -1):

My suggestion would be to change the data structure on the x axis.

This could be achieved through grouping the results eg. monthly users or by shortening the time scale (and probably adding a time filter to change the results depending on the selected time range).

Posting the data the graph is drawn from would probably help this question.